# Downloading and FTP file with a NSOperation

Tags: iphone, ftp, nsoperation

I am trying to download a file from an FTP server using an NSOperation.  My base example for the download is [Apple's Simple FTP project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009243).  In particular, I am using the code from the `GetController` class.  The URL that I am trying to download works fine from there.

In my `NSOperation` subclass, I override the start method and call the `_startRecieve` method found in `GetController`.  The `NSStream` delegate is getting called, but the event is `NSStreamEventErrorOccurred`.

I investigated the error a bit, and it is `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork` error 200, which is `kCFFTPErrorUnexpectedStatusCode`.

Since the code `_startRecieve` code is identical, the only problem that I can think of would be the fact that it is contained in an `NSOperation`. The only thing that looks like it could have problems with an operation `_startRecieve` is this.

```
self.networkStream.delegate = self;
[self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self.networkStream open];
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own NSOperation subclass for networking, why not use QHTTPOperation from Apple's [MVCNetworking](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html) project?

Comment: I was not aware of QHTTPOperation.  It would be a good solution, but it does not work with FTP files unfortunately.  It only works with HTTP.

Comment: I suggest modeling your FTP operation on QHTTPOperation.  Look at the code and you will see all the run loop issues that the author had to deal with.

Comment: Yeah I can get an example from here.  If other people have a similar problem, QHTTPOperation is a subclass of QRunLoopOperation.  Making my operation class a subclass of QRunLoopOperation (plus some other tweaking) did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found my answer helpful.